# Ubuntu 16.04 Remmina connect to Mac with different display resolution

Tags: display, remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

I'm trying to connect via VNC Remote Desktop using Remmina from my Desktop Ubuntu 16.04 (1920x1080) to a MacBookPro Retina (1440x900). The connection seems to work but I cannot scale and Mac's Desktop is too big and doesn't fit Ubuntu display.
Any suggestions?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the left-most button in the Remmina interface? When you hover your mouse over it, it says "Resize the window to fit in remote resolution". I'd love to show you a screenshot of it, but I don't have the reputation to add images. :P I have Remmina v1.1.2 and it works fine when accessing a Mac.

Comment: I have this same issue and this is not a solution (well, I'm connecting to a mac with a different screen resolution anyway). Pushing that button results in an almost portrait-mode view, in which the bottom part of the screen (with the annoying Mac icons) is totally hidden.

Answer (score 0):

On the left most side of the Remmina display, if you hover then you will notice a button with "Toggle Scaled Mode". That button worked in my case. Note that, it disables disables the button with "Resize the window to fit in remote resolution".